# Everything is showing rather than what i need

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to project the fname, lname, and facility name.

```
SELECT `inmate`.`inmate_id`,`inmate`.`fname`,`inmate`.`lname`,`facility_inmate`.`inmate_id`,`facility_inmate`.`facility_id`,`facility`.`name` FROM inmate
LEFT JOIN `prison`.`facility_inmate` ON `inmate`.`inmate_id` = `facility_inmate`.`inmate_id` 
LEFT JOIN `prison`.`facility` ON `facility_inmate`.`facility_id` = `facility`.`facility_id`
```

But i am getting out with extra stuff here

```
inmate_id   fname   lname   inmate_id   facility_id     name
1   Richard     Mongler     1   1   Attica
2   Tom     Brady   2   2   Downstate
3   Tyrone  Jayshon     3   3   Fishkill
```

How can i make it so it doesnt output, `inmate_id, and facility_id`

I want it just to print, `fname, lname, and name`

Comment: This is really basic SQL. Please read any tutorial. You will discover that the columns shown in the result set are those listed after the SELECT keyword.

Comment: Well take the columns you don't need to select out the select clause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then just remove this fields from your `SELECT` clause :

```
SELECT `inmate`.`fname`
     , `inmate`.`lname`
     , `facility`.`name`  
FROM inmate LEFT JOIN `prison`.`facility_inmate` ON `inmate`.`inmate_id` = `facility_inmate`.`inmate_id` 
            LEFT JOIN `prison`.`facility` ON `facility_inmate`.`facility_id` = `facility`.`facility_id`
```